# 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, python-requests

My code works fine for English text, but doesn't work for for Russian search_text. How can I fix it?

Error text

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 41-46: Body ('Москва') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

**My code**

```
import requests

# search_text = "London" # OK: for english text
search_text = "Москва" # ERROR: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 41-46: Body ('Москва')
headers = {
    'cookie': 'bci=6040686626671285074; _statid=a741e249-8adb-4c9a-8344-6e7e8360700a; viewport=762; _hd=h; tmr_lvid=ea50ffe34e269b16d061756e9a17b263; tmr_lvidTS=1609852383671; AUTHCODE=VCmGBS9d9sIxDnxN-hzApvPxPoLNADWCZLYyW8JOTcolv2dJjwH7ALYd8dNP9ljxZZuLvoKsDXgozEUt-PjSwXYEDt4syizx1I2LS58gb49kCFae-5uIap--mtLsff2ZqGbFqK5r7buboZ0_3; JSESSIONID=adca48748b8f0c58a926f5e4948f42c0c0aa9463798a9240.1f3566ed; LASTSRV=ok.ru; msg_conf=2468555756792551; TZ=6; _flashVersion=0; CDN=; nbp=; tmr_detect=0%7C1609852395541; cudr=0; klos=0; tmr_reqNum=4; TZD=6.200; TD=200',
}

data = '''{\n "id": 24,\n "parameters": {\n "query": "''' + search_text + '''"\n }\n}'''

response = requests.post('https://ok.ru/web-api/v2/search/suggestCities', headers=headers, data=data)

json_data = response.json()
print(json_data['result'][0]['id'])
```

I tried

```
city_name = city_name.encode('utf-8')
```

but received `TypeError: must be str, not bytes`

Comment: It looks like the last sentence of the error message tells you what you need to do to fix it.

Comment: Please, see update

Comment: Are you trying to send or receive Russian characters? You need `encode` to encode strings to send and `decode` to decode byte sequences that you receive.

Comment: Try inserting `# coding: UTF-8` as the very first line of your script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding this after the line where you create the data variable before you post the request

```py
data=data.encode() #will produce bytes object encoded with utf-8
```

Answer (score 5):

in my case:

this worked

```
import json
import http.client

f = open('YOURFILE.json', encoding="utf8")

data = json.load(f)

message = json.dumps(data['MESSAGE'],ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
```

this is json file content:

```
{
  "MESSAGE": "یو تی اف 8 کاراکتر"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case which I wanted to return a docx file with farsi name, the following approach worked for me:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import urllib.parse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/download-file")
async def download_file():
    filename = "فایل.docx"  
    file_path = "path_to_your_file.docx" 

    response = FileResponse(file_path, headers={
        "Content-Disposition": f'attachment; filename*=UTF-8\'\'{urllib.parse.quote(filename)}'
    })
    return response
```